# How do I extract values from nested JSON?

Tags: ruby, json, parsing, csv

After parsing some JSON:

```
data = JSON.parse(data)['info']
puts data
```

I get:

```
[
{
"title"=>"CEO",
"name"=>"George",
"columns"=>[
{
"display_name"=> "Salary",
"value"=>"3.85",
}
, {
"display_name"=> "Bonus",
"value"=>"994.19",
}
, {
"display_name"=> "Increment",
"value"=>"8.15",
}
]
}
]
```

`columns` has nested data in itself.

I want to save the data in a database or CSV file.

```
title, name, value_Salary, value_Bonus, value_increment
```

But I'm not concerned about getting `display_name`, so just the values of first of columns, second of columns data, etc.

Ok I tried data.map after converting to hash & hash.flatten could find a way out.. .map{|x| x['columns']}
.map {|s| s["value"]}
tried to get the values atleast separately - but couldnt...

Comment: So what code have you written in an attempt to answer this question? "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist."

Comment: tried.. getting the values by trying to convert into hash and flatten it - and also trying to convert a multidimensional array to multidimensional - but couldnt

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple problem, and resolves down to a couple nested `map` blocks.

Here's the data retrieved from JSON, plus an extra row to demonstrate how easy it is to handle a more complex JSON response:

```
data = [
  {
    "title"   => "CEO",
    "name"    => "George",
    "columns" => [
      {
        "display_name" => "Salary",
        "value"        => "3.85",
      },
      {
        "display_name" => "Bonus",
        "value"        => "994.19",
      },
      {
        "display_name" => "Increment",
        "value"        => "8.15",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title"   => "CIO",
    "name"    => "Fred",
    "columns" => [
      {
        "display_name" => "Salary",
        "value"        => "3.84",
      },
      {
        "display_name" => "Bonus",
        "value"        => "994.20",
      },
      {
        "display_name" => "Increment",
        "value"        => "8.15",
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here's the code:

```
records = data.map { |record|
  title, name = record.values_at('title', 'name')
  values = record['columns'].map{ |column| column['value'] }

  [title, name, *values]
}
```

Here's the resulting data structure, an array of arrays:

```
records
# => [["CEO", "George", "3.85", "994.19", "8.15"],
#     ["CIO", "Fred", "3.84", "994.20", "8.15"]]
```

Saving it into a database or [CSV](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/index.html) is left for you to figure out, but Ruby's [CSV](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/index.html) class makes it trivial to write a file, and an ORM like [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net) makes it really easy to insert the data into a database.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tin... got it working... God I was writing lengthy paragraphs for this... :)  -- About the extra row... yes understand... but I have another json - data = [
  {
    "title"   => "CEO",
    "name"    => "George",
    "columns" => [
      {
        "display_name" => "Address",
        "value"        => "Albany",
      },
      {
        "display_name" => "Phone",
        "value"        => "47123",
      },
      {
        "display_name" => "Mobile",
        "value"        => "784123",
      }
    ]
  } ]     ---- here the initial title name remain the same.. but values inside differ

Comment: So I am trying to join / merge the two before they go into the records... to extract values.. data = data.merge(data1){|key, first, second| first + second } - trying out...

Comment: To Save into CSV in a single line this works...


    File.open("data.csv", "w") {|f| f.write(data.inject([]) { |csv, row|  csv << CSV.generate_line(row) }.join(""))}

Comment: Don't save the CSV like that. Use [the example in the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#class-CSV-label-To+a+File). It's a lot cleaner and works as well.